# how to properly construct and inherit classes?

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, design-patterns, inheritance

I want to write communication interface via serial port. (using Qt)

I have QSerialPort class, which provides interface to work with serial port.
I inherited QMySerialPort from QSerialPort class, which added some functionality and dialog window to config port.

Now I want to write 2 protocol classes:
First - low layer class, sendPacket, parseData methods and etc.. 
Second - high layer: setDeviceID, getDeviceID, onPayload, etc..

How can I do it?
The first thing that comes to mind is create some QSerialInterface meta-class, which will include the objects of QMySerialPort and 2 protocol layers classes.
And I should implement some connection between them.

Such as:

**Protocol class:**
void setPort(QSerialPort *port) { m_port = port; }

**sendPacket method:**
m_port->send(local_data);

But I think this approach is wretched.
Do you have any ideas?
Maybe I should use design patterns here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should narrow down the scope of your question to get a more useful answer. That said, there are a couple of things I'd like to point out.

- Try to keep your UI code separate from your business logic. More specifically, the code for the configuration dialog has no place in `QMySerialPort`.
- Depending on the kind of functionality you're adding over `QSerialPort`, keep in mind that you can use `QSerialPort` through composition instead of inheritance, and in many cases (if not most) the former is preferable.
- In general, try to define the responsibility for each interface/class as narrow and focused as possible. Parsing data should go in a separate interface from sending/receiving individual packets. This way you can substitute different communication mediums while keeping the overall protocol and the objects that deal with it unchanged.
- The `setPort` method is OK, although I personally would pass `port` as parameter to the constructor instead.